# GroupBy SQL to EF Lambda syntax

Tags: entity-framework

I'm currently defeated in my attempts to map the following sql to an EF lambda style query:

sql:

```
SELECT        ResellerId, Name, Month, SUM(MonthTotal) AS MonthTotal
FROM            dbo.View_ResellerYearMonthBase
WHERE        (Year = 2015) AND (EventId > 0) AND (ValidationResponse IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY ResellerId, Month, Name
```

I've tried

```
public JsonResult GetResellerAnnualReportData(int year, bool includeUnValidated, bool includeUnbooked)
{
    var qry = _reportsDal.View_ResellerYearMonthBase.AsQueryable();
    qry = qry.Where(x => x.Year == year);

    if (!includeUnValidated) { qry = qry.Where(x => x.ValidationResponse.Length > 0); }

    if (!includeUnbooked) { qry = qry.Where(x => x.EventId > 0); }

   qry = qry.GroupBy(x => new { x.ResellerId, x.Month, x.Name }).Select(y => new ResellerAnnualReportDto
            {
                ResellerId = y.Key.ResellerId,
                Month = y.Key.Month.Value,
                Name = y.Key.Name,
                SumMonthTotal = y.Sum(z => z.MonthTotal.Value)
            });

    throw new NotImplementedException();//keep the compiler happy for now
}
```

How should I go about achieving the SQL Query with the function parameters (year, includeUnValidated etc)

Comment: Do you get any exception?

Comment: you want to use OrderBy().ThenBy().ThenBy(), not GroupBy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do this:

```
var result = qry.GroupBy(x => new { x.ResellerId, x.Month, x.Name }).
                 Select(y => new  { 
                                      y.Key.ResellerId, 
                                      y.Key.Month, 
                                      y.Key.Name, 
                                      SumMonthTotal = y.Sum(z => z.MonthTotal) 
                                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: That's almost there, but despite using var it seems the qry is expected to be of target type View_ResellerYearMonthBase. I've tried switching the anonymous object for a simple class. I'll update my post...

Comment: @NeilThompson, you should select in the end. See edits.

Comment: Awesome. I'm going to stop and think through how this works. There aren't any compiler errors any more (since your edit). Thanks for getting me back on track.

Comment: This is just a slower version of an already existing method though, groupby accepts 3 different delegates

Answer (score 1):

```
.GroupBy(key => new { key.ResellerId, key.Month, key.Name},
         el => el.MonthTotal,
         (key, el) => new ResellerAnnualReportDto
         {
            ResellerId = key.ResellerId,
            Month = key.Month,
            Name = key.Name,
            MonthTotal = el.Sum(s => s.MonthTotal)
         }).ToList();
```

This uses [the overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548731(v=vs.100).aspx) with keyselector, elementselector and resultselector. This way you avoid making the `IGrouping<key,value>` and get the results you want immediately. Couldn't test though.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderDerck I will study this. It will help fill in some of the missing parts of my EF skills

Comment: First element says what it needs to be grouped by, second parameter says what you need to take from each element in a group, 3rd parameter lets you use the key and the collection of all the elements you selected in a group and create a custom anonymous object with them. This avoids the wasted work of creating an `IGrouping`  :)

Comment: What do you call immediately? This is linq 2 sql and it will first translate your code to raw sql and send that statement to engine. I see no difference here.

Comment: You think it's the same query? Can't test it atm :/

Comment: @AlexanderDerck, I can not check too :) but it should be the same if not more complex(I mean Sql statement). The whole idea of linqtosql is first prepare the statement and when you call ToList the statement will be sent to Sql engine, so in your version it will not be sent earlier. It will be sent exactly at the time mine will be sent.